# Chrome Extension Data Server

Tags: javascript, html, database, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I am making a chrome extension and wish to store data that other people who are using the extension can access. I am trying to make a replacement for the YouTube dislike button so once somebody clicks the dislike button and has my extension installed it will send it to a data server and will stay there, it can be changed once another person has disliked the video but also other people can view the number of dislikes as there will be a little text just as there is at the moment. I am pretty new to the Chrome Extension world only starting around a week ago. So far I've mainly just been researching but have made it so it detects the click of the Dislike Button but if you guys have any suggestions or maybe code blocks I could learn off feel free to reply to this! Have a good day!

CupCat

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.